# 'Extends' and 'Implements' Java equivalents in C#

Tags: java, c#

What is the C# equivalent syntax for the following Java statement:

```
public class Lion extends Animal implements Diurnal()
{
}
```

Comment: You should consider prefixing your interfaces with I. The answers given below are correct but will cause a confusion as which is a class and which is an interface here.

Comment: There shouldn't be any parentheses in the interface, not even in Java.

Answer (score 90):

- Animal is Base class
- Diurnal is an Interface

the inheritance could be declared like this.

```
public class Lion : Animal, Diurnal
{

}
```

In `C#`, you can inherit one base class and can be multiple Interfaces.

One more tip, if you are making an `Interface` in C#, prefix it with `I`. eg `IDiurnal`

Comment: Just a note. Base class must come before any interfaces.

Answer (score 21):

```
public class Lion : Animal, // base class must go first
                    Diurnal // then interface(s) if any
{
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Would look something like this:

```
public class Lion :Animal, Diurnal {
}
```

Where `Animal` is a *class* and `Diurnal` is an *interface*.

Please note, that according to the C# naming convention, *interface* has to have "I" infront of its name, so finally it *should* look like this:

```
public class Lion :Animal, IDiurnal {
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In C#, there is uniform syntax for extending class and implementing interface.

```
public class Lion : Animal, Diurnal {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to write down first base class like(`Animal` is base class),
lately interfaces like as(`Diurnal` is a Interface)

```
public class Lion : Animal, Diurnal {}
```

Answer (score 2):

the first name after : is the extended class, after comes the implemented interfaces

```
public class Lion : Animal, Diurnal
{
}
```

c# do not allow multiple class extension, but you can implement many interfaces

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public class Lion : Animal, Diurnal
{
}

interface Diurnal
{
}

class Animal
{
}
```

Class `Animal` was inherited by `Lion` class. `Diurnal` class is interface.

Comment: When posting code, please format it as code. Also, when posting code, add some explanation as to indicate what that code shows. Also, when answering a question, ask yourself whether your answer will add anything to the existing answers.

Comment: Also, Welcome to [so]! It's a great place to learn how to communicate programming knowledge, and I hope you'll continue to contribute (and improve)!